# Kähler-hyperbolic and Kobayashi-hyperbolic complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry

I look for a clear proof of the implication Kähler-hyperbolic in the sense of Gromov implicate Kobayashi-hyperbolic for compact complex manifolds.

Comment: Corollary 4.2 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.06918.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the reference Is it the same proof as Gromov's theorem